# Universal application

Tags: iphone, ipad, hardware, device

How to make universal app for iphone and ipad. How we detect the device whether it is for iPhone or iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in Xcode 3**

select your target in Xcode, right-click and use the “Upgrade Current Target for iPad…” command.

**in Xcode 4**

click on the project and go to the target. In Summary tab, change Device to Universal.

I used

```
UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

for detecting iPad.

Comment: and if i want to detect the iPod and iPhone then: UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomiPod and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be using `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` and `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`.

Answer (score 0):

Personnally, I used this method in my appdelegate

```
+ (BOOL)isPad
{
    NSLog(@"--------- %@ ---------", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
    NSRange range = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] rangeOfString:@"iPad"];
    return !(range.location==NSNotFound);
}
```