# Multiple build targets for iPhone, iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

I have built my iPhone app targetting OS 3.0
Now I would like to also build an iPad version of my app which should have a minimum OS deploy of 3.2 if remember correctly?

I have made a duplicate of my app target and changed the 'device' setting in the 'Summary' tab to 'iPad'. When I run this target in the ipad simulator I get a 'minified' iphone version running inside the ipad simulator (with the magnifier 2x button on the bottom right). I figured this was because the .xib files that i'm using are too small for the ipad?

How do I create iPad compatible .xib files, and how do I link them to my iPad target build?

Comment: Do the seach on Universal app here on stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321932/universal-application this may help you.

Comment: How do I make a build for os 3.0 (iPhone) and another for a higher os 3.2 (iPad)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For universal Application u have to set target for both iPhone/iPad.
You have to design two different xib for both iphone & ipad.

For identified device place following condition in "App-delegate":
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) //ipad
    {
        isIphone=FALSE;
    }
    else //iphone
    {
        isIphone=TRUE;
    }