# Iphone/Ipad app developement

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Hi I have wrote an application which is suitable for iphone (haven't uploaded to appstore yet)
I want this app to be supported on iPad as well.

Do I need to open a new project and create a separate app for iPad or is there a way to create a single app for both ?

Thanks

Comment: Search in google for creating universal apps for iOS / iPhone SDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Universal application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321932/universal-application)

Comment: Have you tried to find by your self on google?

Comment: iPhone Fun - yes I did. I did not know it was referred as Universal apps. And I thought this forum is exactly for that purpose so your very clever response is not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice tutorial to start porting of app from iphone to ipad.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

Answer (score 0):

no need to create a new project, if u like to release for iPad also you need to resize for the all the classes, whichever view suits for the iPad, and also check it in your ipad,then deploy target should be both for iPad and iphone